# Creating a Symlink in an NTFS share

Tags: linux, ntfs, arch-linux, samba, symbolic-link

I am currently on Arch Linux accessing Samba shares of an NTFS drive connected to a windows machine. I want to be able to create Symlinks from my Arch Linux machine in the Samba shares. I have googled this a bit and the usual response is adding a few lines to Samba.conf:

```
follow symlinks = yes
wide links = yes
unix extensions = no
```

My understanding is that this code only allows me to use Symlinks that are already created. Is there anyway to create them from my Arch Linux machine?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know, but I can confirm that your samba config will do what you want, if you get it working. I do that all the time on my nas, but it is Ext4 on both locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those lines in `smb.conf` are for configuring a Samba server, i.e. a server running in Linux. It changes how the server interprets symlinks in a directory it shares. It has nothing to do with using smbclient (or some other client) to access shares on a Windows machine.

As far as I know, NTFS doesn't support UNIX-style symlinks. I believe Microsoft added something to the filesystem to implement something similiar, but I haven't seen it used, and I don't know if the SMB/CIFS protocol even supports them.

Comment: Is it possible to share an ext4 partition from windows then? My only other option is going Linux on the Samba machine which I don't really want to set up

Comment: Not really. There used to be a driver to mount ext2 under windows, and it could do ext3 without the journal (which is dangerous if a crash happens). I don't know if it supports ext4 or if it was ever updated to Vista/7/8. I suspect the driver doesn't expose symlinks to Windows (how would it interpret them?)

Comment: try using mklink in windows and see if that works. per wikipedia, the extension was made in part for POSIX compability so its likely it will work. see description and syntax here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link

Comment: To anyone else who reads this. It's not about what the network drive is partitioned as. It's just that you can't create symlinks over a Samba. Or at least I couldn't. I tried :P. Thank you everyone who tried to help.

Comment: @Chris, you able not be able to create a symlink OVER samba (a symlink where the target is at an smb:// address), but you can create a symlink between two locations on the same system, and configure samba to deference that link so that clients will see a folder where the symlink resides, and in it, the content that the symlink refers to. you could of course mount the smb share and then refer to its mount location with your symlink. perhaps I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: The reason I need symlinks is to build AOSP. The script that inits and syncs the repo always throws error 95 which means that it couldn't create the symlink. I googled it quite a bit and no one seems to have an answer for it, probably because no one has tried it due how poor the performance would be. I still wanted to try it out over a gigabit network to see how it would do.